# Returning a pointer to the beginning of a linked list after adding nodes?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int num;
} Node;


Node *insert(int i) {
    Node *head;
    for (int c = 0; c < i; c++) {
        head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        head.num = i;
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

The insert function is supposed to create a linked list and add numbers from 0 to i to that linked list. However, it is also supposed to return a pointer to the beginning of the list/the list itself and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I've tried to make a pointer and set it equal to head after adding the first node, but it only returns the first node and not the entire list. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Your bigger problem is that you're not assigning any value to head->next, so you're not really creating a linked list at all, just a bunch of nodes floating around in space

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Wouldn't the num value of head->next be 1 since I'm reassigning head? So it would be a linked list of 0->1->2->3.....->c, right?

Comment: When you assign `head = head->next;` you are assigning an uninitialized pointer over the pointer you just allocated.  You've leaked memory and stored an undefined pointer.  You have BIG problems.  The function is also supposed to return a value but doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to remember the previous node, so you can assign its next pointer.  When you add a node, set its next pointer to the old head, and it now becomes the new head of the list.  Which you can just return after the last iteration of the loop.

```
Node *insert(int i) {
    Node *head, *prev = NULL;
    for (int c = 0; c < i; c++) {
        head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        head->num = i;
        head->next = prev;
        prev = head;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Update: to insert each new element at the end of the list, you need a bit more bookkeeping:

```
Node *insert(int i) {
    Node *last_node = NULL;
    Node *first_node = NULL;
    for (int c = 0; c < i; c++) {
        Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        node->num = i;
        node->next = NULL;
        if (!last_node) {
            // Remember the first node, so we can return it.
            first_node = node;
        }
        else {
            // Otherwise, append to the existing list.
            last_node->next = node;
        }
        last_node = node;
    }
    return first_node;
}
```

Comment: This works, but the list is now from i to 0 instead of 0 to i. Is there any way to make it so that it doesn't reverse the order of the list?

Comment: @P.Sate: Yes, it can be done.  You should be able to do it.  You'll need to keep a pointer to the last item in the list, as well as the first.  You'll return the first, but add new items after the last.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as introducing another variable. You currently have `head` to track the head of the list; add another to track the *tail* of the list:

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int num;
} Node;

Node *insert(int i) {
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head.num = 0;
    tail = head;
    for (int c = 1; c < i; c++) {
        // allocate a new node at the end of the list:
        tail->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        // set "tail" to point to the new tail node:
        tail = tail->next;
        tail->num = c;
    }

    return head;
}
```

You could also add a special case for `i == 0`, if necessary.

By the way - and I realise this is possibly a task given to you as an exercise - but `insert` is a terrible name for a function that actually creates and fills an entirely new list.